# Force ggplot2 to apply a separate legend for each geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the chart below, the triangles mapped using `geom_point` are both in the same legend. Essentially, I would like each `geom_` to have their own separate legend instead. How would I go about doing so?

[image]

Here's my code for reproducibility:

```
mydf <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2000, 3), rep(2002, 3), rep(2004, 3), rep(2006, 3), rep(2008, 3), rep(2010, 3), rep(2012, 3), rep(2014, 3), rep(2016, 3)),
                 answer = rep(c("A great deal", "Hardly any", "Only some"), 9),
                 result = c(0.3015940, 0.1399303, 0.5584757, 0.2269548, 0.1792754, 0.5937698, 0.2955301, 0.1309859, 0.5734840, 0.3008197, 0.1344499,
                            0.5647303, 0.1919454, 0.2026290, 0.6054256, 0.1059793, 0.4190533, 0.4749674, 0.1190636, 0.3631279, 0.5178085, 0.1518314,
                            0.3181203, 0.5300483, 0.1424715, 0.3094615, 0.5480669))
mydf$year <- factor(mydf$year)
mydf$answer <- factor(mydf$answer)
triangle_up <- data.frame(year = c(2004, 2008, 2010),
                        direction = c("A great deal", "Hardly any", "Hardly any"),
                        result = c(0.2955301, 0.2026290, 0.4190533))
triangle_up$year <- factor(triangle_up$year)
triangle_up$direction <- factor(triangle_up$direction)
triangle_down <- data.frame(year = c(2002, 2008, 2010, 2010, 2012),
                            direction = c(rep("A great deal", 3), "Only some", "Hardly any"),
                            result = c(0.2269548, 0.1919454, 0.1059793, 0.4749674, 0.3631279))
triangle_down$year <- factor(triangle_down$year)
triangle_down$direction <- factor(triangle_down$direction)

ggplot(mydf, aes(x = year, y = result)) + geom_line(aes(colour = answer, group = answer)) +
geom_point(data = triangle_up, aes(x = year, y = result, group = direction, fill = direction), shape = 24, size = 3) +
geom_point(data = triangle_down, aes(x = year, y = result, group = direction, fill = direction), shape = 25, size = 3)
```

Comment: You get one legend per aesthetic. So, in the post you are getting on legend for `color` and another for `fill`. Probably it is not possible to get one legend per geometry.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the use of multiple data frames to store values. It would be better to add a column to the `mydf` data frame to store the `direction` variable. Confusingly, you have used `answer` as the variable name in `mydf`, but `direction` to store the same values in the other data frames.

So here is the new `mydf` with values "up", "down" or NA in the `direction` column:

```
mydf <- structure(structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2016, 2016, 2016), answer = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A great deal", 
"Hardly any", "Only some"), class = "factor"), result = c(0.301594, 
0.1399303, 0.5584757, 0.2269548, 0.1792754, 0.5937698, 0.2955301, 
0.1309859, 0.573484, 0.3008197, 0.1344499, 0.5647303, 0.1919454, 
0.202629, 0.6054256, 0.1059793, 0.4190533, 0.4749674, 0.1190636, 
0.3631279, 0.5178085, 0.1518314, 0.3181203, 0.5300483, 0.1424715, 
0.3094615, 0.5480669), direction = c(NA, NA, NA, "down", NA, 
NA, "up", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "down", "up", NA, "down", "up", 
"down", NA, "down", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("year", 
"answer", "result", "direction"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = 
"data.frame"))
```

Now you can plot with separate legends for `direction` and `answer`. Shapes are specified manually using `scale_shape_manual`, using `breaks` to omit the NA values. For line colour, we use `scale_color_manual` and override the legend mapping so as only lines, not shapes, are shown.

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(year, result)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = answer, color = answer)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = direction, fill = answer), size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(25, 24), breaks = c("down", "up")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = rep(NA, 3)))) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273466/3817004) has demonstrated how to create the chart *if the plot data are supplied in the proper format*. However, this is only the second part of the story.

The answer below tries to suggest a way how the OP can create the plot data from his original data.frames `mydf`, `triangle_up`, and `triangle_down`. The goal is to have all plot data in one data.frame.

#### Original data

as provided by OP but without factorization (this will be done later when needed):

```
mydf <- data.frame(year = c(rep(2000, 3), rep(2002, 3), rep(2004, 3), rep(2006, 3), rep(2008, 3), rep(2010, 3), rep(2012, 3), rep(2014, 3), rep(2016, 3)),
                 answer = rep(c("A great deal", "Hardly any", "Only some"), 9),
                 result = c(0.3015940, 0.1399303, 0.5584757, 0.2269548, 0.1792754, 0.5937698, 0.2955301, 0.1309859, 0.5734840, 0.3008197, 0.1344499,
                            0.5647303, 0.1919454, 0.2026290, 0.6054256, 0.1059793, 0.4190533, 0.4749674, 0.1190636, 0.3631279, 0.5178085, 0.1518314,
                            0.3181203, 0.5300483, 0.1424715, 0.3094615, 0.5480669))
triangle_up <- data.frame(year = c(2004, 2008, 2010),
                        direction = c("A great deal", "Hardly any", "Hardly any"),
                        result = c(0.2955301, 0.2026290, 0.4190533))
triangle_down <- data.frame(year = c(2002, 2008, 2010, 2010, 2012),
                            direction = c(rep("A great deal", 3), "Only some", "Hardly any"),
                            result = c(0.2269548, 0.1919454, 0.1059793, 0.4749674, 0.3631279))

triangle_up
#  year    direction    result
#1 2004 A great deal 0.2955301
#2 2008   Hardly any 0.2026290
#3 2010   Hardly any 0.4190533

triangle_down
#  year    direction    result
#1 2002 A great deal 0.2269548
#2 2008 A great deal 0.1919454
#3 2010 A great deal 0.1059793
#4 2010    Only some 0.4749674
#5 2012   Hardly any 0.3631279
```

Apparently, `triangle_up` and `triangle_down` are rows selected by some means from the master data.frame `mydf` containing data points which should be emphasized in the chart by being plotted using special symbols. Note that the OP has decided to rename the `answer` column to `direction`.

#### Preparing and joining the data

`data.table` is used for these tasks, here.

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used

# combine separate triangle data.frames into one data.table,
# thereby adding an id column to indicate origin of each row
triangles <- rbindlist(list(triangle_up, triangle_down), idcol = "arrow")
# turn id col into factor, giving meaningful labels
triangles[, arrow := factor(arrow, labels = c("up", "down"))]

triangles
#   arrow year    direction    result
#1:    up 2004 A great deal 0.2955301
#2:    up 2008   Hardly any 0.2026290
#3:    up 2010   Hardly any 0.4190533
#4:  down 2002 A great deal 0.2269548
#5:  down 2008 A great deal 0.1919454
#6:  down 2010 A great deal 0.1059793
#7:  down 2010    Only some 0.4749674
#8:  down 2012   Hardly any 0.3631279

# rename direction column to make join easier
setnames(triangles, "direction", "answer")

# coerce mydf to data.table and right join with triangles, i.e.,
# result contains all rows of mydf
mydf2 <- triangles[setDT(mydf), on = .(year, answer, result)]
# turn year into factor to have ggplot using a discrete scale
mydf2[, year := factor(year)]
```

Finally, all data required for plotting are combined in one data.table

```
mydf2
#    arrow year       answer    result
# 1:    NA 2000 A great deal 0.3015940
# 2:    NA 2000   Hardly any 0.1399303
# 3:    NA 2000    Only some 0.5584757
# 4:  down 2002 A great deal 0.2269548
# 5:    NA 2002   Hardly any 0.1792754
# 6:    NA 2002    Only some 0.5937698
# 7:    up 2004 A great deal 0.2955301
# 8:    NA 2004   Hardly any 0.1309859
# ...
#19:    NA 2012 A great deal 0.1190636
#20:  down 2012   Hardly any 0.3631279
#21:    NA 2012    Only some 0.5178085
#22:    NA 2014 A great deal 0.1518314
#23:    NA 2014   Hardly any 0.3181203
#24:    NA 2014    Only some 0.5300483
#25:    NA 2016 A great deal 0.1424715
#26:    NA 2016   Hardly any 0.3094615
#27:    NA 2016    Only some 0.5480669
#    arrow year       answer    result
```

#### Plotting

To plot the data, the code from  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273466/3817004) can be used with two modifications:

```
ggplot(mydf2, aes(year, result)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = answer, color = answer)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = arrow, fill = answer), size = 3) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(25, 24), breaks = c("down", "up")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"),
                     guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = rep(NA, 3)))) +
  theme_light()
```