# Remove specific markers from legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry if this question has already been answered but I could not find the solution to what I am after. I have a plot that uses both `geom_line` and `geom_point`. The result of this is that in the legend, it adds both a line and a point when they should have one or the other. I want to keep the circles for the data `tg1` and `tg2` and remove the line and then do the opposite to the data `full` *i.e.* keep the line but remove the circle. I have seen that something like this works where you want to remove dots from all of the legend entries but nothing to only do specifics [Removing ggplot2's geom_point icons from the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272804/removing-ggplot2s-geom-point-icons-from-the-legend). Can anyone help? Thanks.

[image: plot]

#code for plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidypaleo)

ggplot(LGRSL, aes(x =mmsl , y = Age))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic(12)+
  geom_point(data=tg1,aes(x=mmslc,y=Year,col="Fort Denison 1"),pch=1,size=2)+
  geom_point(data=tg2,aes(x=mmslc,y=Year,col="Fort Denison 2"),pch=1,size=2)+
  geom_lineh(data = full, aes(x=Lutregalammslc,y=Year,col="Full budget"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("grey15","grey50","black"))
  

## data

## tg1

structure(list(Year = 1886:1891, SLR = c(6919L, 6935L, 6923L, 
6955L, 6956L, 6957L), mmsl = c(-0.158, -0.142, -0.154, -0.122, 
-0.121, -0.12), m = c(6.919, 6.935, 6.923, 6.955, 6.956, 6.957
), GIA.correction = c(-0.02814, -0.02793, -0.02772, -0.02751, 
-0.0273, -0.02709), SLRc = c(6.89086, 6.90707, 6.89528, 6.92749, 
6.9287, 6.92991), mmslc = c(-0.19667, -0.18046, -0.19225, -0.16004, 
-0.15883, -0.15762)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

##tg2

structure(list(Year = 1915:1920, SLR = c(7011L, 6929L, 6987L, 
6945L, 6959L, 6951L), mmsl = c(-0.066, -0.148, -0.09, -0.132, 
-0.118, -0.126), m = c(7.011, 6.929, 6.987, 6.945, 6.959, 6.951
), GIA.correction = c(-0.02205, -0.02184, -0.02163, -0.02142, 
-0.02121, -0.021), SLRc = c(6.98895, 6.90716, 6.96537, 6.92358, 
6.93779, 6.93), mmslc = c(-0.09858, -0.18037, -0.12216, -0.16395, 
-0.14974, -0.15753)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

##full

structure(list(Year = 1900:1905, Lutregala = c(-0.103609677, 
-0.118603251, -0.134550791, -0.105553735, -0.103983082, -0.121731984
), Wapengo = c(-0.095213147, -0.096005337, -0.115700625, -0.097696891, 
-0.084444784, -0.109161066), Tarra = c(-0.106672829, -0.109537943, 
-0.135256365, -0.101357772, -0.089716518, -0.104258351), Lutregalammsl = c(-0.292863465, 
-0.307857039, -0.323804579, -0.294807523, -0.29323687, -0.310985772
), Wapengommsl = c(-0.257028279, -0.257820469, -0.277515756, 
-0.259512023, -0.246259916, -0.270976198), Tarrammsl = c(-0.30925682, 
-0.312121933, -0.337840355, -0.303941762, -0.292300508, -0.306842342
), LgGIAc = c(-0.01921, -0.01904, -0.01887, -0.0187, -0.01853, 
-0.01836), WapGIAc = c(-0.02486, -0.02464, -0.02442, -0.0242, 
-0.02398, -0.02376), TarGIAc = c(-0.02373, -0.02352, -0.02331, 
-0.0231, -0.02289, -0.02268), Lutregalammslc = c(-0.312073465, 
-0.326897039, -0.342674579, -0.313507523, -0.31176687, -0.329345772
), Wapmmslc = c(-0.281888279, -0.282460469, -0.301935756, -0.283712023, 
-0.270239916, -0.294736198), Tarmmslc = c(-0.33298682, -0.335641933, 
-0.361150355, -0.327041762, -0.315190508, -0.329522342)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

##LGRSL

structure(list(depths = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), RSL = c(0.047746907, 
0.025564293, 0.021733558, 0.007855661, -0.004909879, 0.01747051
), RSLerror = c(0.058158556, 0.057902654, 0.057988654, 0.057957388, 
0.057905405, 0.057226072), Age = c(2017.456716, 2013.594255, 
2006.92838, 1999.675523, 1994.729181, 1990.518154), Ageerror = c(0.373138707, 
0.77640096, 1.430582242, 1.627131115, 3.222393394, 3.239674718
), mmsl = c(0.01993169, -0.002250924, -0.006081659, -0.019959556, 
-0.032725096, -0.010344707)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

##LGRSLgp

structure(list(Age = 1892:1897, mean = c(-0.298147401, -0.304630597, 
-0.31023294, -0.315506983, -0.321225142, -0.327190675), error = c(0.051858047, 
0.04985084, 0.047760525, 0.045624121, 0.043505044, 0.041477551
), min = c(-0.246289354, -0.254779758, -0.262472416, -0.269882862, 
-0.277720098, -0.285713124), max = c(-0.350005447, -0.354481437, 
-0.357993465, -0.361131103, -0.364730186, -0.368668226), x = c(-0.02125, 
-0.02108, -0.02091, -0.02074, -0.02057, -0.0204), meangia = c(-0.276897401, 
-0.283550597, -0.28932294, -0.294766983, -0.300655142, -0.306790675
), rate = c(NA, -4.967327, -4.946326, -4.964493, -4.977451, -4.911859
), raterror = c(NA, 3.581013, 3.796417, 4.022157, 4.226762, 4.255126
), mmsl = c(-0.325962618, -0.332445814, -0.338048157, -0.3433222, 
-0.349040359, -0.355005892)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reproducible example - but could you clarify which dataset you dputtted corresponds to which dataset in your code (i.e. which is LGRSL?). Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have added them in with headers to hopefully make this clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way.
Override the guide legend with a list of vectors of values for each of the aesthetics involved, `shape` and `linetype`. Note the different ways to specify what is to be removed.

I have also simplified the code a bit.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

colrs <- c("Fort Denison 1" = "grey15",
           "Fort Denison 2" = "grey50",
           "Full budget" = "black")
legnd <- list(shape = c(1, 1, NA), 
              linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"))

bind_rows(
  tg1 %>% mutate(col = "Fort Denison 1"),
  tg2 %>% mutate(col = "Fort Denison 2")
) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = mmslc, y = Year, colour = col)) +
  geom_point(pch = 1, size = 2) +
  geom_lineh(data = full, aes(x = Lutregalammslc, col = "Full budget"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = colrs, 
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = legnd)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)
```

[image]